# Morena version 6 vs 7

Tags: java, wia, twain, morena

We are currently using the Morena 6 lib to scan images. Morena 6 internally uses the TWAIN protocol and we got a big issue. All our scanners install a 32 bit TWAIN driver, so we cannot use it when we start a 64 bit version of Java. We can now switch to Morena 7 which uses the WIA protocol. But I don't know whether it solves the above described problem. I think I'm not the first who has such problems. Probably somebody can tell me whether this protocol change can solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

In Morena 7.1.36, there is the ability to use 32bit Twain drivers in 64bit Java.
It internally uses some 64bit surrogate process and is partly coded in assembly.

You can use it like that:

```
Configuration.setMode(Configuration.MODE_TWAIN_ENABLED);
```

or with native UI dialog:

```
Configuration.setMode(Configuration.MODE_NATIVE_UI | Configuration.MODE_TWAIN_ENABLED);
```

Answer (score 1):

64-bit Java libraries *should* include 32-bit compatibility.  I can't tell you if WIA will solve this as I haven't used WIA or Morena 7.  Your Morena license will cover both 6 and 7, so you could definitely run a test application using it.  What I can tell you is that WIA is the "user friendly" dumbed down version that doesn't support as many nice features as TWAIN had.

As for the architecture issue and solving for Morena 6, I have successfully run in Chrome and Firefox (both 64-bit, before NPAPI [and therefore Java] support was dropped) using 64-bit Java on 32-bit TWAIN.  From what I gather though you're probably running an application, which theoretically should make this easier.  You'll just need to find out how to force your application to run in 32-bit mode.

Answer (score -1):

I had not much Knowledge about morena7 Please find the documentation in the following link

http://www.gnome.eu/Morena/doc/tutorial7.html

http://gnome.sk/Morena/morena.html